# QTP - See through invisible window (JBoss error mask upon returning to page from a popup)

Tags: jboss, window, qtp, invisible

Steps:

1. QTP identifies a few links on a web App.
2. I click on this link (using qtp).
3. Application opens a popup to change a few values.
4. I submit the Image button after changing the values.
5. I return back to the original page, which is open in the background (never closed).
6. But QTP now does not recognize those few links (as said in point 1), instead it only shows a hierarchy upto Page as shown below:

`Browser("name:=JBoss Web/2.1.7 - Error report").Page("title:=JBoss Web/2.1.7 - Error report")`

I have to use a `Browser("name:=JBoss Web/2.1.7 - Error report").refresh` code to get the properties visible again everytime I get back from the popup.

Notes - This occurs on a few machines (different behavior on different machines). Very few systems do not show the JBoss error when accessing through QTP. OS, QTP and browser versions are same with default settings.

Upon changing registry value as shown below, I was able to access all of the web elements most of the times. However, at times, I get the JBOSS error (browser,page) mask again which seems to be impenetrable.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mercury Interactive\QuickTest Professional\MicTest\Packages\StdPackage\Settings]
"SkipWndMovedOut"=dword:00000001
```

Any suggestions on what needs to be done to access all the elements every time - by surpassing the JBOSS error mask page every time?

Thanks,
Anuroop.

Comment: Could the Error report be something as a window with debug information? That could explain the behaviour on the machines where it does not occur. Can you tell me why you don't want to use the  `Refresh` method on the browser each time you return? That sounds like a suitable solution (/work around). BTW, your title 'See through invisible window' made me smile.

Comment: That was a workaround - the Browser Refresh code.  We had to disable BHOManager class as a permanent solution (never permanent I guess).  So far it's been around a month and we haven't faced any other issues, so we are going ahead with this solution of disabling BHOManager Class (addon in the browser).  Yeah - See through invisible window - hehe ;)

Answer (score 1):

What version of QTP are you using? 
This sounds like a known bug which was fixed for QTP10 by hotfix QTPWEB_00065 (there are hotfixes for other versions too).

I suggest you contact HP support in order to get the relevant hotfix.

As a workaround in the meantime you can use `Browser`'s undocumented `RefreshWebSupport` method which reconnects QTP to the page without refreshing the page.

Comment: Hey, thanks.  We are using version 11.  Solution for us was to disable the BHOManager class.  Ever since we never encountered JBOSS error mask page.